# Difference b/w web content cache and application cache

Tags: firefox, caching, browser-cache

What's the difference b/w web content cache and application cache.
On my system Firefox is using a space of 400MB for web content cache.

Answer (score 0):

Application cache refers to the mechanism by which a Web application can store data on the server side. The actual store varies, it can be a database, in-memory, etc. This is usually done for performance reasons. For example, a call to get data from a database may take considerable amount of time and may not change often. Once the data is fetched initially, the developer may chose to put it in App Cache to get it quickly from memory next time as opposed to call the DB again.

Browser-cache refers to the data stored on the user's computer (client). Browsers, for example, may cache images, style sheets, etc. This depends on how the server responds to the browser requests. For example, a server may send certain headers in the response indicating that a javascript file should be cached until changed on the server, etc. This way, Browsers improve the user experience by not re-downloading data unnecessarily multiple times.